# ExtJS chart font bug on IE8

Tags: extjs, internet-explorer-8, charts

Hello I have problem with charts on IE8
This is how it looks on every browser [image]

And that is how it looks like on IE8 [image]
I will appreciate some help for fixing this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on Windows 7 (and is this application being accessed via an intranet)?

- If so - go to Tools -> Compatibility View Settings, and uncheck
  'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View'.
- Also, either add a header via your web application, or use a `<meta
  http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">` in the
  `<head>` section of the page to force IE=Edge.

The only time I saw this problem was with versions of IE < 10 on Windows 7 getting thrown into 'IE8/9 Compatibility View' with Document Mode being automatically set to IE 7 standards.

> Aside: No changing of chart themes or styles would fix this. I tried
>   every method of changing styles and creating a new theme to be
>   applied, and as long as the Browser Mode was wrong, IE decided to use
>   whatever that script font is.
>
> In my case - it didn't make a load of sense as to why this was
>   happening to our sales guy's laptop, as our site forces
>   `http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1"`, but somehow
>   his browser was set to `Browser Mode: IE 9 Compatibility Mode -
>   Document Mode: Internet Explorer 7 Standards`.

- Upon opening up the Developer Tools in IE, and changing his browser
  back to standards - everything worked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and yes I'm with Win7 ... I fix the problem somehow but I don't remember how but probably thru css - anyways I'm pretty sure youre solutions is good.